# Defining file path in js

Tags: javascript, directory

I have a small confusion in js path defining. Please find the below code.

```
var pathA = 'myFolder/project/css/';
```

and I have another folder called 'js' under 'project'. So instead of having another variable like below,

```
var pathB = 'myFolder/project/js/';
```

Is there a way to point 'js' folder using 'pathA' variable.

Comment: You can use `..` to go up, so `pathB + "../js/"` probably.

Comment: Why don't you do a `var rootPath = 'myFolder/project/'; ` Then `var pathA = rootPath + 'css/';` and `var pathB = rootPath +'js/'; `

Comment: @Terence: pathA is already defined globally which I cant edit. Just trying to make use of it to make a new path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well do it like you would deal with paths in the command line or similiar. You can use `..` to move up a layer so instead of `pathB`, you could use `pathA + "../js/"`

Comment: In that case, the result would be 'myFolder/project/css/../js'

Comment: yes, which refers to the same folder, otherwise you can replace the rest of the string, you want me to show how to do that?